# XMPP and PHP streaming

Tags: php, ajax, tcp, streaming, xmpp

im creating a website which uses php to connect to an XMPP server , and send a message
However, im having a problem with sending/receiving messages ..
Question is do i have to reconnect and send username/password everytime i make a request ( send a message ) ?
how to avoid reconnecting ?

This is how i connect :

```
    $this->_socket = fsockopen("sever.tld", 5222, $errno, $errstr, 30);
```

i send messages using fwrite Like this :

```
    fwrite($Socket, $data);
```

i read messages using fread Like this :

```
    $response = @fread($this->_socket, 1024);
```

Comment: How are you connecting? Please show us some code.

Comment: i've added the code to the post

Answer (score 3):

The approach you're using is not going to work in the long run.

Because a PHP instance effectively ceases to exist when it's finished sending a page back to the browser client, the connection you make to the XMPP server is closed. This means that all state (TLS session, authentication, &c) is lost.

So yes, if you do it this way, you'd have to reconnect and re-authenticate on every page load.

Please don't do it this way. You may use an XMPP-server-side adapter such as [XMPP over BOSH](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0206.html), designed for this purpose, or an HTTP-server-side persistent connection via some daemon or longer-lived process which your PHP instances share.

Comment: Unfortunately i do not have access to the XMPP-Server-side, The only access i have is over the HTTP-Server-side

Comment: @user1175643 Well, you've got a problem. The lifetime of the PHP instances are shorter than the lifetime of the XMPP session, but the XMPP session is abandoned when the TCP connection is closed. You need something to act as a gatekeeper here.

Comment: @user1175643 I believe xmppphp has support for persistent connections.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following loop to prevent the connection from closing:

```
while (!feof($this->_socket)) {

}
```

And place all of your logic inside. It will run endlessly in a loop while the connection is still active (which it would be until you kill it).